# MetaData Copy-Item is not bringing the name of the user

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy the metadata of the file when I copy the files over to another directory. 
However, I noticed that the user name (the person who last modified the file or created the file) is not coming over with the Metadata. 
I looked into all the properties of the File Object and couldn't see any property related to the author of the file.

[image]

Here is my powershell script

```
$Source = "C:\Users\someuser\SharePoint\Budget - Documents\Temp Datasources\Test"
$Destination = "C:\Users\someuser\SharePoint\Storm - General\Test"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source 

ForEach($File In $Files){
    #Construct Destination file path
    $DestinationFile = [System.IO.FileInfo] (Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $File.Name)
    Write-Verbose -Message "Destination File $DestinationFile " -Verbose

    Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $DestinationFile -Force

    #Verify if the file was copied and exists before copying over properties and attributes. 
    if($DestinationFile.Exists){
        $DestinationFile.CreationTime = $File.CreationTime
        $DestinationFile.LastAccessTime = $File.LastAccessTime
        $DestinationFile.LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
        $DestinationFile.Attributes = $File.Attributes        

    }    
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp.txt" | Get-Member -MemberType Property` doesn't list `Author` as an available properties. However a quick test of `Copy-Item` shows that these "extended properties" (e.g. author) are copied with the file [I assume they are actually embedded in the file]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion [Here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/421503-powershell-help-getting-file-details)
it would appear that those details aren't actually part of the properties and are extensions of the word and excel documents. You will have to load up a com object for Word or Excel and use that to read those extra properties.

The link I provided does have link to the ScriptingGuy Post where he covers this (only for Word, but I'm sure you can modify it for excel)